# How would you find how many times one array is repeated in another one?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, if you were given {1,2} as the small array and {1,2,3,4,1,2,1,3} as the big one, then it would return 2.

This is probably horribly incorrect:

```
public static int timesOccur(int[] small, int big[]) {
    int sum= 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<small.length; i++){
        int currentSum = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<big.length; j++){       
            if (small[i] == big[j]){
                currentSum ++;
            }   
            sum= currentSum ;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet. If you post some code we can help you come to a solution.

Comment: It's basically a [String matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) problem, where the alphabet of the "characters" is integers.

Comment: if small was {1,1} and big was {1,1,1} would it return 1 or 2?

Comment: It would return 2 and order matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @AndyTurner mentioned, your task can be reduced to the set of well-known string matching algorithms.

As I can understand you want solution faster than O(n * m).

There are two main approaches. First involves preprocessing text (long array), second involves preprocessing search pattern (small array).

1. Preprocessing text. By this I mean creating [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) or [LCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array) from your longer array. Having this data structure constructed you can perform a binary search to find your your substring. The most efficient time you can achieve is O(n) to build LCP and O(m + log n) to perform the search. So overall time is O(n + m).
2. Preprocessing pattern. This means construction DFA from the pattern. Having DFA constructed it takes one traversal of the string (long array) to find all occurrences of substring (linear time). The hardest part here is to construct the DFA. [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) does this in O(m) time, so overall algorithm running time will be O(m + n). Actually KMP algorithm is most probably the best available solution for this task in terms of efficiency and implementation complexity. Check [@JuanLopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728596/how-would-you-find-how-many-times-one-array-is-repeated-in-another-one/32729218#32729218)'s answer for concrete implementation.

Also you can consider optimized bruteforce, for example [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), it is good for practical cases, but it has O(n * m) running time in worst case.

## UPD:

In case you don't need fast approaches, I corrected your code from description:

```
    public static int timesOccur(int[] small, int big[]) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < big.length - small.length + 1; i++) {
            int j = 0;
            while (j < small.length && small[j] == big[i + j]) {
                j++;
            }
            if (j == small.length) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Pay attention on the inner while loop. It stops as soon as elements don't match. It's important optimization, as it makes running time almost linear for best cases.

**upd2:** inner loop explanation.

The purpose of inner loop is to find out if smaller array matches bigger array starting from position `i`. To perform that check index `j` is iterated from 0 to length of smaller array, comparing the element `j` of the smaller array with the corresponding element `i + j` of the bigger array. Loop proceeds when both conditions are true at the same time: `j < small.length` **and** corresponding elements of two arrays match.

So loop stops in two situations:

1. `j < small.length` is **false**. This means that `j==small.length`. Also it means that for all `j=0..small.length-1` elements of the two arrays matched (otherwise loop would break earlier, see (2) below).
2. `small[j] == big[i + j]` is **false**. This means that match was not found. In this case loop will break before `j` reaches `small.length`

After the loop it's sufficient to check whether `j==small.length` to know which condition made loop to stop and hence know whether match was found or not for current position `i`.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the question about performance or complexity analysis. Did I miss something?

Comment: @sprinter, probably it was I who missed something. I noticed that author proposed O(n * m) solution and called it horribly incorrect. That made me think that author wants **faster** solution. Apparently I was wrong and author just wanted **correct** solution.

Comment: yes I'm not certain either. I gave an answer on the assumption that they were an early stage learner and wanted some hints. But it's a fairly ambiguous question. Enjoyed your answer either way.

Comment: Hi. I am very new to Java, but I have an exam coming up so I'm reviewing. Can you please explain what the while loop is saying? I'm confused about order of operations as well as the "&&".

Comment: What I enjoy the most about this answer is its completeness. StackOverflow isn't a forum, where the only goal is to guess what the OP meant. An answer in SO must be written for all the future users that may land here after a search. And this one clearly does.

Comment: @Aivean Thanks for the explanation. It makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple subarray matching problem. In Java you can use `Collections.indexOfSublist`, but you would have to box all the integers in your array. An option is to implement your own array matching algorithm. There are several options, most [string searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) can be adapted to this task.

Here is an optimized version based on the [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). In the worst case it will be O(n + m), which is better than the trivial algorithm. But it has the downside of requiring extra space to compute the failure function (`F`).

```
public class Main {
    public static class KMP {
        private final int F[];
        private final int[] needle;

        public KMP(int[] needle) {
            this.needle = needle;
            this.F = new int[needle.length + 1];

            F[0] = 0;
            F[1] = 0;
            int i = 1, j = 0;
            while (i < needle.length) {
                if (needle[i] == needle[j])
                    F[++i] = ++j;
                else if (j == 0)
                    F[++i] = 0;
                else
                    j = F[j];
            }
        }

        public int countAt(int[] haystack) {
            int count = 0;
            int i = 0, j = 0;
            int n = haystack.length, m = needle.length;

            while (i - j <= n - m) {
                while (j < m) {
                    if (needle[j] == haystack[i]) {
                        i++;
                        j++;
                    } else break;
                }
                if (j == m) count++;
                else if (j == 0) i++;
                j = F[j];
            }
            return count;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new KMP(new int[]{1, 2}).countAt(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3}));
        System.out.println(new KMP(new int[]{1, 1}).countAt(new int[]{1, 1, 1}));
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't thoroughly looked into your code, but KMP algorithm should work in O(n + m) in worst case.

Comment: Is there anything in the question that makes us think that OP is at all interested in performance? Surely the question is basic enough that it's clear they want a nice simple readable solution. This is hardly that.

Comment: @sprinter Is there anything in the question that make us think they don't? I wanted to give an answer from the performance perspective (as everyone else was addressing other points). I don't think that is a fault that deserves a downvote (I don't know if you downvoted, but someone did). Readabilty isn't the only thing that counts.

Comment: @Aivean KMP works in `O(n + m)` in worst case for finding a single match or many non-overlapping matches. In this question we are looking for all the matches. From the performance perspective, the real best answer would be using a suffix array, but if I got a downvote just by taking time to write KMP in Java, I can't even imagine what would happen if I implemented Ukkonen's algorithm here.

Comment: @JuanLopes, probably you are using KMP in wrong way then. Correct approach will be iterate bigger array exactly once. If match is found you need to increment the resulting counter and make the same fallback as if match failed. The search itself (after construction of fallback table) should be O(n). Anyway, upvoted you for trying.

Comment: @Aivean You are completely right! Thanks. Updated my answer with the correct version. But your answer is way more complete than mine, so still upvoting yours.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than posting a solution I'll provide some hints to get your moving.

It's worth breaking the problem down into smaller pieces, in general your algorithm should look like:

```
for each position in the big array
     check if the small array matches that position
         if it does, increment your counter
```

The smaller piece is then checking if the small array matches a given position

```
first check if there's enough room to fit the smaller array
    if not then the arrays don't match
otherwise for each position in the smaller array
    check if the values in the arrays match
        if not then the arrays don't match
if you get to the end of the smaller array and they have all matched
    then the arrays match
```

Comment: @pnuts I think I won't bother with this sort of answer in the future. As you say it's mostly the code that users are after!

Answer (score 0):

Though not thoroughly tested I believe this is a solution to your problem. I would highly recommend using Sprinters pseudocode to try and figure this out yourself before using this.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] smallArray = {1,1};
    int[] bigArray = {1,1,1};
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++)
    {
        boolean flag = true;
        if(bigArray[i] == smallArray[0])
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < smallArray.length; x++)
            {
                if(i + x >= bigArray.length)
                    flag = false;
                else if(bigArray[i + x] != smallArray[x])
                    flag = false;

            }

            if(flag)
                sum += 1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sum);

}
```

}